# Decreasing the heap with sbrk can collide with the data segment?

Tags: memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory, memory-segmentation, sbrk

I know that allocating too much free memory to the heap can collide with the stack, but what about the data segment? Because sbrk can be used with a negative value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: I will try. The `void *sbrk(intptr_t increment)` function can have "increment" as a negative value, so I have a very simple example in which I use sbrk will try to reduce the heap. If I put `sbrk(-2)` at the beginning of a main function, before putting anything else, this is considered for the heap to be colliding with the data segment? @manetsus